# Divorce and Social Sec, Pension, and 401K

Tags: united-states, 401k, pension, social-security, divorce

I am 65 while my spouse is 52. My spouse has been the sole breadwinner of the family and we've been married for 25 years

If we were to get a divorce, can I start collecting now on my spouse's Social Security and/or Pension? If we divide the 401K evenly, can I start withdrawing from my half with no penalty?

Comment: Depends on what the QDRO says. Also, do you want to start collecting spousal benefits from Social Security _before_ or _after_ your divorce?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to start collecting Social Security after the divorce.

Comment: Note - the QDRO applies to the 401(k) and maybe pension. I don't think there's any way for a divorce settlement to alter what you collect from Social Security.

Answer (score 1):

**If we were to get a divorce, can I start collecting now on my spouse's Social Security and/or Pension?**

[Yes you can.](https://www.ssa.gov/planners/retire/divspouse.html)

> If you are divorced, but your marriage lasted 10 years or longer, you
>   can receive benefits on your ex-spouse's record (even if they have
>   remarried) if:
>
> - You are unmarried;
> - You are age 62 or older;
> - Your ex-spouse is entitled to Social Security retirement or    disability benefits and
> - The benefit you are entitled to receive based on your own work is    less than the benefit you would receive based on your ex-spouse's
>     work.

**If we divide the 401K evenly, can I start withdrawing from my half with no penalty?**

Since you are over the age of 59.5, you can withdraw from your 401k [without penalty](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/401k-resource-guide-plan-participants-general-distribution-rules).